# no sediment in my cider home brew kit

Tags: sediment

I've recently purchased and set up a cider homebrew kit, but after 9 days I've had absolutely no sediment at all. Have I done something wrong? I've followed the instructions to the word.

Comment: I've never brewed anything that didn't have some sediment visible the first time I looked. Tell us what else you can see, we need more info.

Comment: Have you seen any evidence of fermentation? Have you compared the gravity with the original reading?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no sediment then likely your yeast is dead and you should probably get some new yeast and add it in.